# How can I make this menu in bash error me if the input option is incorrect

Tags: bash, input, menu

I have this menu but the option to give the user an error if the input text is wrong doesn´t work.

```
if  [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" -a -f "$1" ]
then

dts=($(cat $1 | cut -d: -f$2))

        for i in ${!dts[@]}
        do
                echo "$i) ${dts[$i]} "
        done

        read   -p "Select a user to delete: " OKSELUSRGRP
        p=$( echo $OKSELUSRGRP | grep -E ^[0-${#dts[@]}]$ )

                if [  -n "$p" ]
                then
                OKSELUSRGRP=${dts[$p]}
                else
                OKSELUSRGRP=""
                fi

else
        echo "Error, select a correct option"
        sleep 1
fi
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You want it to error out if the user sets an invalid value to `OKSELUSRGRP` correct?  The way it currently is written the only way that `echo "Error, select a correct option"` && `sleep 1` will be executed is if: $1 is null or $2 is null or $1 is not a file.  The check for validity happens within that first if statement so that's where you would need to put the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this, although I'm not quite sure what your script is doing.

```
if  [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" -a -f "$1" ]; then
    dts=($(cat $1 | cut -d: -f$2))
        for i in ${!dts[@]}; do
            echo "$i) ${dts[$i]} "
        done
        read -p "Select a user to delete: " OKSELUSRGRP
        p=$(echo $OKSELUSRGRP | grep -E ^[0-${#dts[@]}]$)
        while [ -z "$p" ]; do
            echo "Error, select a correct option"
            sleep 1
            read -p "Select a user to delete: " OKSELUSRGRP
            p=$(echo $OKSELUSRGRP | grep -E ^[0-${#dts[@]}]$)
        done
    OKSELUSRGRP=${dts[$p]}
else
        echo "
Usage: $0 [file] [something else]   

$0 can be used to select users or something.
"
fi
```

Comment: You are a genius!! Thanks you very much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: NP, glad I could help.  `while` loops are my go-to when forcing users to give a specific input although I guess an `until` loop could be used just the same (except opposite).

Comment: Hmmm. Seems like this might break if ```${#dts[@]}``` is greater than 9.